# My Font Face Doesn't Work

Tags: asp.net, css, font-face, woff

I'm preaparing a  simple web site. But my font-face doesn't work on Google Chrome.

Here is [my page](http://zinzinzibidi.com/leaf_solutions/referanslar)

My CSS codes:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600);

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

My web.config data

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

It works fine on Firefox but not fine on Chrome. I tried "fonts folder method" and "ttf fonts" on my project but it didn't change.

I have a suspicion about woff files but I can't change it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your web.config won't have any bearing on the matter, as that's for your server, but the font is being loaded from Google's server. How do you know it's not working? I loaded your site in Chrome and it looks like it's in Open Sans to me... In Chrome's tools, the computed style is, indeed, Open Sans. (See [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/09/DevTools-answers-What-font-is-that) to learn how to inspect the font that's really being used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use that - paste this link in head section:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: or try this way `@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600');`

Comment: Dude. Something has change. I think it is OK. I'm trying to understand. Check it out with CTRL + F5

Answer (score 1):

What version of chrome are you using? Seems to work fine on Version 31.0.1650.63.

```
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```